# How to access session variable inside a template range?

Tags: go

I want to add an `Edit` button which appear only for moderators:

```
{{range $n := .articles}}
   <p>{{$n.Content}} </p>
   {{ if .is_mod}}
      <button> Edit </button>
   {{end}}
{{end }}
```

I have already set `is_mod` as a boolean variable in session and passed it to template. However, it is not a field in the `Article` struct, so, I get this error:

> executing "content" at <.is_mod>: is_mod is not a field of struct type
>   model.Article.

One obvious solution is to make a new struct in the controller which includes a `IsMod` field and pass that to template, but that is messy and inefficient so I'd rather avoid it if possible and looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass session variable to the template. I didn't tried it, but you can try something like this:

```
c.HMTL(http.StatusOK, "template_name", gin.H {
  "articles": articles,
  "is_mod": is_mod,
})
```

The above syntax is for `gin-gonic/gin` framework. .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H {
  "posts": posts,
  "some_data": "Home page posts",
})
```